# Immediate mode texturing weird output

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, cimg

I'm trying to simply draw an image with OpenGL's immediate mode functions.
However, my output is kinda weird. I tried a few Texture parameters - but i get the same result, sometimes with different colors. I kinda can't figure out the problem, but i figure it's either the image loading or texture setup. I'll cut to the case, here is how i generate my texture (in a `Texture2D` class):

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

A call to `glTexImage2D` follows, like this: `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, _width, _height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);`, where data is an array of `unsigned char` set to 255, white. I then load a PNG file with CImg, like this:

```
CImg<unsigned char> image(_filename.c_str());
image.resize(m_Width, m_Height);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_ID);
if(image.spectrum() == 4)
{
    unsigned char* data = image.data();
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, m_Width, m_Height, GL_RGBA,   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
}
else if(image.spectrum() == 3)
{
    unsigned char* data = image.data();
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, m_Width, m_Height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
}
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

But when i try to draw the texture in immediate mode like this (origin is upper left corner, notice the red rectangle arund the texture is intentional):

```
void SimpleRenderer::drawTexture(Texture2D* _texture, float _x, float _y, float _width, float _height)
{
    _texture->setActive(0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
      glVertex2f(_x, _y);

      glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
      glVertex2f(_x + _width, _y);

      glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
      glVertex2f(_x + _width, _y + _height);

      glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
      glVertex2f(_x, _y + _height);
    glEnd();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glColor3ub(strokeR, strokeG, strokeB);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
      glVertex2f((GLfloat)_x, (GLfloat)_y);
      glVertex2f((GLfloat)_x+_width, (GLfloat)_y);
      glVertex2f((GLfloat)_x+_width, (GLfloat)_y+_height);
      glVertex2f((GLfloat)_x, (GLfloat)_y+_height);
    glEnd();
}
```

I expect an output like this within the rectangle (debugging the same PNG within the same program/thread with CImg):

[image: Mario expected]

But i get this:

[image: Mario actual]

Can anyone spot the problem with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How pixel data are stored with CImg](http://cimg.eu/reference/group__cimg__storage.html):

> The values are not interleaved, and are ordered first along the X,Y,Z and V axis respectively (corresponding to the width,height,depth,dim dimensions), starting from the upper-left pixel to the bottom-right pixel of the instane image, with a classical scanline run.So, a color image with dim=3 and depth=1, will be stored in memory as :R1R2R3R4R5R6......G1G2G3G4G5G6.......B1B2B3B4B5B6.... (i.e following a 'planar' structure)and not as R1G1B1R2G2B2R3G3B3... (interleaved channels),

OpenGL does not work with planar data, it expects interleaved pixel data.  Easiest solution is to use a library other than CImg.

This does not fix the scaling issues, but it's a good place to start.

Comment: great. But CImg is so easy to use and work with :( and ive set up all my dependencies for it... Guess i should read the documentation more thoroughly next time.

Comment: There are *tons* of image loading libraries out there.  SDL_Image, DevIL, SOIL, etc.

Comment: I'm currently looking at these. I dismissed SDL_Image as i don't want to use SDL (please don't ask why :D), i have problems trying to compile DevIL with MinGW 5.1, and SOIL seems to only load directly to OpenGL textures, which is unacceptable for me.

Comment: Almost sounds like you're trying to fail on purpose... just download the DevIL binaries if you can't compile it, or use SDL even though you don't like it.

Comment: Well, im not trying to fail on purpose, but trying to set up DevIL with CMAKE just throws project errors, and generating doesn't produce any Makefiles as a consequence^^ Well, i guess i have to use a bigger library then. Kinda liked CImg, especially with its integrated image manipulation functionalities.

Comment: Does CImg provide any functionality to retrieve the data in interleaved format? Cannot check the documentation right now, i also guess i could just convert the image format myself. Shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: You're using OpenGL, which is a hundred times better than CImg for doing image manipulation.  If you want a smaller library, you can use WinCodec, but this will only work on Windows.

Comment: Well yes, but then i'll have to write the algorithms myself xD

Answer (score 0):

Use `CImg<T>::permute_axes()` to transform your image buffer to interleaved format, like this :

```
CImg<unsigned char> img("imageRGB.png");
img.permute_axes("cxyz"); // Convert to interleaved representation
// Now, use img.data() here as a pointer for OpenGL functions.
img.permute_axes("yzcx");  // Go back to planar representation (if needed).
```

CImg is indeed a great library, so all these kind of transformations have been planned in the library.

Comment: Also beware than when you apply `CImg<T>::permute_axes()` on your `CImg<unsigned char>` instance, this also swaps its dimensions accordingly to the given permutation. So `img.spectrum()` becomes `img.width()`, etc.. (width()->height() and height()->depth()).